# template class and free function namespace problems with implementation

Tags: c++, linker, namespaces, undefined-reference

I have a class defined like this (trivial includes and preprocessor wrappers, etc. are omitted, but they are there):

```
In Matrix.h

namespace matrixmanip {
template<typename T>
class Matrix {
    public:
        void someFunc() const;
    //...
};

template<typename T>
void Matrix<T>::someFunc() const {
    //...
}
} // namespace matrixmanip
```

---

```
In bitTransform.h

#include "Matrix.h"

namespace matrixmanip {
Matrix<char> bitExpand(const Matrix<char> &mat);
} // namespace matrixmanip
```

---

```
In bitTransform.cpp

#include "bitTransform.h"

using namespace matrixmanip;

Matrix<char> bitExpand(const Matrix<char> &mat) {
    mat.someFunc();
    //...
}
```

---

```
In tester.cpp

#include "Matrix.h"
#include "bitTransform.h"

matrixmanip::Matrix<char> A ... // construct a character matrix, details of which are unimportant here
matrixmanip::Matrix<char> B = matrixmanip::bitExpand(A);
```

However, when I compile and link like this:

```
g++ -c tester.cpp
g++ -c bitTransform.cpp
g++ -Wall -O2 tester.o bitTransform.o -o tester
```

I get an undefined reference error, specifically

```
/tmp/ccateMEK.o: In function `main':
tester.cpp:(.text+0xbf9): undefined reference to `matrixmanip::bitExpand(matrixmanip::Matrix<char> const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why am I getting this error? It seems to me that my namespace resolution is okay and my linkage is fine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bitExpand` defines a free function in global namespace, not in `matrixmanip` namespace. `using` directive does not move definitions into the namespace being used. You should put definition in proper namespace directly:

```
namespace matrixmanip
{
    Matrix<char> bitExpand(const Matrix<char> &mat)
    {
        mat.someFunc();
       //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively `Matrix<char> matrixmanip::bitExpand(const Matrix<char> &mat)` if the OP insists on the using directive.

Comment: @Aconcagua - I'm with VTT on this though. Declarations should be put into namespaces explicitly. If only to lessen the mental burden of needing to remember which part of the declaration is resolved to what name in which namespace. So, only if the OP insists, otherwise, this answer is the golden standard.

Comment: @StoryTeller I assume from your sentence that good practice is that described by VTT, right? The only reason I was using `using` (I know it's generally bad practice) is because this site: http://julio.meroh.net/2013/12/header-files-avoid-c-using-directives.html said it was perfectly fine. Apparently not though. I could find much other documentation on namespace and `using` in implementation files.

Comment: @JonathanLee - Name lookup is C++ is terribly complex at times. So I say yes, this answer has the best practice. The one least likely to stop you from actual coding with mysterious errors. And like I already mentioned, it's somewhat easier (on the programmer) to figure out where to look for names when you write it explicitly like this.

Comment: @JonathanLee `using` directive would be helpful if `Matrix<char>` was declared in different namespace. Though in this case it would be a good idea to bring only `Matrix<char>` into `matrixmanip` namespace by declaring a type alias like `using CharMat = matrix::Matrix<char>;` rather than pull all the names from that namespace with `using namespace matrix;`

Comment: @StoryTeller *'Declarations should be put into namespaces explicitly.'* - actually, it's the definition, declaration already occured in header - and declaration even *needs* to be in namespace - or have I missed a change in the standard (again)?

Comment: A definition is also a (possible re-)declaration, so no contradiction :)