# The right way to use namespace directive in C++

Tags: c++

In various authoritative sources I see various ways to use namespaces.
The C++ standard does not focus on proper use of namespace.

Suppose we have the follows code:

**example.h**

```
namespace Example {
    class MyClass
    {
    public:
        MyClass();
    } 
}
```

and here are 2 ways for implementation:

**example1.cpp**

```
#include "example.h"

using namespace Example;

MyClass::MyClass();
```

**example2.cpp**

```
#include "example.h"

namespace Example
{
    MyClass::MyClass();
}
```

Both implementations compile without warning in gcc, therefore, it is rather a question of purity or beauty of the code. But anyway, what are the advantages or disadvantages of both methods?

Comment: If you are looking for "standard" style-related practices, you should be looking at the [core guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md), not the standard itself.

Comment: @AlexF, That's not a rule of thumb. `using namespace` in a header is a recipe for disaster. In cpp files, it's not fundamentally dangerous, but wether it's advisable is another story altogether.

Comment: Since both are valid, this is a matter opinion.

Comment: Here's an [example for your where the two produce vastly different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53578238/template-class-and-free-function-namespace-problems-with-implementation). I already commented there on which I think it makes preferable. It's subject to opinion, IMHO.

Comment: @PasserBy doing something just because it is valid in c++ is not a really good guidance. Some of the things that are valid are good options, some are uncommon, some are bad, and some are really bad.

Comment: `using namespace ...` is always potentially dangerous. It's never bad to limit a scope to its absolute minimum affect.

Answer (score 1):

The two examples are not the same:

The first (`using namespace Example;`) will let the compiler see all the used namespace as it is in the current namespace. (mean you don't need to specify the namespace unless there is ambiguity with other namespace)

the second (`namespace Example {...}`)will add symbols and code to the namespace. but from outside the namespace it won't be seen as it is in the current namespace.

- You don't need to declare `using` for the current namespace.
- a block can be only in a single namespace, but can use multiple namespace.

---

for example:

```
//consider the following namespace
Namespace A
{
  void f()
  {

  }
}
```

from the `main` you have two options:

Call with namespace

```
int main()
{
  A::f();
  ...
}
```

Or add `using` and call without the namespace.

```
using namespace A;
int main()
{
  f();
  ...
}
```

But you can't add the main into the namespace, since it won't be found by the compiler:

```
namespace A {
  int main()
  {
    f();
    ...
  }
}
```

will result error:

> undefined reference to `main'

Comment: While your anser is technically correct, I fear it might be misleading for OP since in his example he is defining symbols that have already been declared within that namespace.

Comment: @Frank Added examples

Comment: Thanks @SHR for the answer! But as @Frank already noticed my answer was a bit different. In my example `MyClass` already defined inside namespace in right and correct way. The only question - is it right? Or, more correctly - if there are 2 ways to do something, what one should I prefer? As for me I prefer `using namespace` directive. But it is possible that each method has its drawbacks ...